# How to get quoted arguments in the correct way?

Tags: shell, zsh

I've got function

```
calc() {echo "${1}"|bc -l;}
```

it works for 2+2 but when I want something alike 10^4

```
calc 10^4
zsh: no matches found: 10^4
```

yes I'm getting the same with bc -l

```
>>echo 10^4|bc -l
zsh: no matches found: 10^4
```

but to solve it I've added quotes

```
>>echo "10^4"|bc -l
10000
```

how to implement it in function? if I do `"\"${1}\""` it will just echo the string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is a special character when `EXTENDED_GLOB` option is enabled in `zsh`. It's expanded before your function is called, so there's no workaround possible *inside the function*.

You can disable `EXTENDED_GLOB` altogether:

```
setopt no_extended_glob
```

or provide an alias for interactive use, which would expand into `noglob calc`, preventing filename expansion:

```
alias calc='noglob calc'
```